# The mobile version slides into two slides: left to right

Tags: html, css, frontend

I don`t know why, but the mobile version of website has some lags. The mobile version of website slides into two slides: left to right. This bug appears on every page of website. The url to check the lag is [this](https://novostroyka.shahar.uz/)

[image: Slides to the right side]
[image: Slides to the left side]

Comment: Please provide your code here, not a link to your website.

Comment: try adding `overflow` property to body like this `body{overflow-x: hidden;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have large of padding size.

below code is work

```css
.google-auto-placed * {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}


/* mobile size */
@media screen and (max-width: 765px){

.google-auto-placed * {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm find your trouble
It's about a line css code

BAD CODE :

```
#content #main {
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
```

}

GOOD CODE

```
#content #main {
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
```

}